# Blob data updation failed in liferay-6.1.2-ce-ga3 bundled with jboss

Tags: java, jboss, blob, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I have a requirement of inserting and updating blob data in liferay portlet project.I am using liferay-6.1.2-ce-ga3 for development.
My service.xml has following blob field

```
 <column name="applicationData" type="Blob" db-name="application_data" />
```

After service build I have successfully inserted the blob data using service builder generated classes.

```
   myEntity.setApplicationData(blobdata);  
   myEntityLocalServiceUtil.addMyEntity(myEntity);
```

I tried to update blob data as follows

```
  myEntity.setCachedModel(false);    
  myEntity.setApplicationData(blobdata);
  myEntityLocalServiceUtil.updateMyEntity(myEntity,false);
```

But everything except blob data is getting updated. When I checked the **BatchSessionImpl** source, I noticed that there is no method like **session.saveOrUpdate(model)** call in it's update method which normally does blob update by skipping **session.merge(model)**.

Below is the update method of BatchSessionImpl class

```
public void update(Session session, BaseModel<?> model, boolean merge)
    throws ORMException {

    if (merge || model.isCachedModel()) {
        session.merge(model);
    }
    else {
        if (model.isNew()) {
            session.save(model);

            model.setNew(false);
        }
        else {
            session.merge(model);
        }
    }

    if (!isEnabled()) {
        session.flush();

        return;
    }

    if ((PropsValues.HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE == 0) ||
        ((_counter.get() % PropsValues.HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE) == 0)) {

        session.flush();
    }

    _counter.set(_counter.get() + 1);
}
```

In my case **session.merge(model)** in the else case is getting invoked. Is there any thing specific with liferay-6.1.2-ce-ga3 bundled with jboss so that we can update blob data?. Can someone suggest me some workarounds.?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by creating an ext plugin. I made changes in ext-impl for BatchSessionImpl class for the update method as follows

```
public void update(Session session, BaseModel<?> model, boolean merge)
    throws ORMException {

    if (merge || model.isCachedModel()) {
        session.merge(model);
    }
    else {
        if (model.isNew()) {
            session.save(model);

            model.setNew(false);
        }
        else {
            session.saveOrUpdate(model);
        }
    }

    if (!isEnabled()) {
        session.flush();

        return;
    }

    if ((PropsValues.HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE == 0) ||
        ((_counter.get() % PropsValues.HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE) == 0)) {

        session.flush();
    }

    _counter.set(_counter.get() + 1);
}
```